# MS Word Macros 2003 - 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

I work in a remote region with limited resources and technical expertise as a Project Manager and a new project I just got handed was the testing of MS Word 2003 macros on a MS Word 2007 platform. The Macros were initially developed by Corel a few years ago when we migrated they migrated that specific division from WordPerfect to MS Office 2003.

I have a test workstation with Office 2007 installed and followed the steps required to get the Macros work to no avail. Any tips and recommendations would be appreciated. I do have experience in VBA and XML coding but the VBA was about 10 years ago and I haven't looked at XML code in at least 4 years.

If I can sollicit some high level suggestions, if coding needs to changed or updated, I can try to figure it out or contract it out but just want to make sure that I have exhausted all other options prior opting for that route.

Thanks

Comment: "followed the steps required to get the Macros work to no avail" - in which case, you can conclude that the Macros aren't compatible with Office 2007?

Comment: Did you step through the code? What lines are broken? Please provide a little more that 'do not work'. Some sample code is always good.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will get any useful answers in this forum, which concerns itself with programming questions. But you might want to try [**this discussion group**](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.word.newusers/topics?lnk=srg), which seems to be just what you want.